# OR-port $A\cdot B$: its conditional probabilities with zero working probability for each component? Reductio ad absurdum?

Tags: probability, logic, conditional-probability

I made this statement $P(T|A)=P(T|B)=0=P(T|\neg A)=P(T|\neg B)$ with a simple OR-gate where $P(A)=0$, $P(B)=0$ and $T=A\cdot B$ i.e. $P(T)=P(A\cup B)$.

> [image]

**What are the conditional probabilities of the system i.e. $P(T|A)$, $P(T|\neg A)$, $P(T|B)$ and $P(T|\neg B)$?**

Answer (score 1):

Suppose A works, what is the probability that the system works i.e. $P(T|A)$? Look A has 0% working probability i.e. $P(A)=0$ so what does the phrase *"A works"* mean here? The term *"working"* can mean at least two things: $P(A)=1$ or $P(A)>0$. The latter requires thinking probabilities with intervals.

The below threads address the aroused issues so far.

**Sub-problems**

1. **Solved** [$P(T\cap \neg B)$ if $P(T)=P(A\cup B)$ where $P(A)=0$ and $P(B)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314427/pt-cap-neg-b-if-pt-pa-cup-b-where-pa-0-and-pb-0)
2. **Solved** [Complement and Negation: $P(A)=0\rightarrow P(\neg A)=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314431/complement-and-negation-pa-0-rightarrow-p-neg-a-1)
3. [Conditional probabilties in the OR-gate $T=A\cdot B$ with zero-probabilities in $A$ and $B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314483/conditional-probabilties-in-the-or-gate-t-a-cdot-b-with-zero-probabilities-in)