# $P(T\cap \neg B)$ if $P(T)=P(A\cup B)$ where $P(A)=0$ and $P(B)=0$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314408/or-port-a-cdot-b-its-conditional-probabilities-with-zero-working-probability) became too long so succintly:

> **What is $P(T\cap \neg B)$ if $P(T)=P(A\cup B)$ (OR-gate) where $P(A)=0$ and $P(B)=0$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(A)=0$ and $P(B)=0$ then $P(A\cup B)=0$ so $P(T)=0$ so $P(T\cap{\rm anything})=0$.

Comment: What about this $P(T\cap \neg B)=P(\neg T \cup B)$? $P(\neg T)=1$ because of $P(T)=0$? $P(B)=0$ by definition. What is the intersection or the union? 0 or 1? I do here the step of reductio ad absurdium but I cannot see where.

Comment: $T\cap\neg B$ is the *complement* of $\neg T\cup B$, so their probabilities add up to $1$.

Comment: Of course, $P(A)^C=1-P(\neg A)$ -- sorry haven't studied probability for years so have to recap, yes that is correct +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The realization $P(A)^C=1-P(\neg A)$ solved a problem in the original thread, namely the case when a system works with zero-probability-working components. It was not *reductio ad absurdum*. We need a new concept called *interval probabilities* to specify the phrases such as *"working component A"* meaning $P(A)>0$.

Let's dig into this with a few examples.

**What about if $\neg A$ works and $\neg B$ works i.e. $P(\neg A\cap \neg B)=1$ when $P(A)=0$ and  $P(B)=0$?**

> We have $P(A\cup B)=1-P(\neg A\cap \neg B)$ so $P(\neg A\cap \neg B)=1-P(A\cup B)=1-(0+0)=1.$ So the system -- the OR-port -- works i.e. $P(T)=1$ but how is this possible with a system where each component is broken? Is this Reductio ad absurdum or is the thinking correct i.e. it is possible to get the system working with zero-probability-working components?

**System's working when $P(\neg A)$ working and $P(A)=0$. What does it mean that $P(\neg A)$ is working?**

> We know $P(\neg A)=1$ because of $P(A)=0$ for a part in the OR-system that has no-working component. We could also use the earlier formula for verification i.e. $P(\neg A)=1-P(A)=1-0=1$. Now $$P(T|\neg A)=P(T\cap \neg A)/P(\neg A)=P(T\cap \neg A)=0$$ and $$P(T|\neg B)=P(T\cap \neg B)/P(\neg B)=P(T\cap \neg B)=0$$
>
> because the system cannot work and the part is working $\{0\}\cap \{1\}=\emptyset$. This is because the probability of the system to work is always 0 because each component has zero probability even though the assumption $\neg A$ works aka $P(\neg A)\in [1,0[$ where the term *"working"* means that the component has non-zero working probability.

**INTERVAL PROBABILITIES**

> I need interval probabilities to attribute specific mathematical meaning to the phrases such as *"working component A"* aka $P(A)>0$.
>
> **Example**
>
> > *Does the system $T$ aka the OR-gate work if $P(A)\in]0,0.1]$ and $P(B)\in [0.9,1[$?*
> >
> > Now $P(\neg A\cap \neg B)=1-P(A\cup B)$ where $P(A\cup B)\in [0.9,1[$ so $P(\neg A\cap \neg B)\in ]0,0.1].$ So the system works with the probability range $]0,0.1]$.