# Help with negations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Are the following negations correct? If they are correct, can they be worded better? IF they are wrong, what are the proper negations and why? Please keep any answer/help simple because I am a beginner soon to be undergradute student. I did not do truth tables yet, nor have I done quantifiers yet. I am looking for simple worded help for negations sentence examples like the ones I attempted here.

1 - Problem: All the integers are positive

My Answer: There exists at least one integer that is not positive

2 - Problem: The boiling temperature of water is 98 degrees Celsius

My Answer: The boiling temperature of water is NOT 98 degrees Celsius

I believe I can simplify this to: The boiling temperature of water is greater than 98 degrees

3 - Problem: 100 is a multiple of 5

My Answer: 100 is NOT a multiple of 5

I believe I can simplify this to: 5 does not divide 100

4 - Problem: All students do not have 3 legs

My Answer: It is not the case that all students do not have 3 legs

I believe I can simplify this to: There exists at least one student with 3 legs

5 - Problem: There are 13 items in a baker's dozen

My Answer: There are not 13 items in a baker's dozen

I thank anyone ahead of time for the help. I am slow, and trying to learn.

Comment: Why do you think, you could simplify to „The boiling temperature of water is greater than 98 degrees“? But the others seem correct to me:)

Comment: In line with the comment of @Henry, if you take a false statement and negate it, the result must be a true statement.  Suppose instead that the original statement had been the false statement that the boiling point of water is $~110^\circ~$ and that you had *attempted to negate it* to the boiling point of water is greater than $~110^\circ.~$  Then, both the original statement and your attempt at negation would be false statements.  This implies that your attempt to negate the statement would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, to easily parse these, it may be best to express these in quantifiers *(even if you haven't done them yet: if nothing else, you can just use the words instead of the symbols)*:

- $\forall$ means "for all"
- $\exists$ means "there exists" or "there is some"
- $P(x)$ can be taken to mean "a proposition $P$ for which $x$ holds true"
- $\neg P(x)$ likewise means "$P$ is false for $x$"

Then the negation of a statement has you interchange every $\forall$ and $\exists$ for the other, and replace $P(x)$ with $\neg P(x)$.

For example: "all numbers in $S$ are positive" can be translated into

$$(\forall x \in S)(x > 0)$$

which has negation

$$(\exists x \in S)(x \le 0)$$

(where $P(x)$ is the statement $x>0$): the negation is "there is some number in $S$ which is nonpositive".

---

> 1 - Problem: All the integers are positive
>
> My Answer: There exists at least one integer that is not positive

This is fine.

---

> 2 - Problem: The boiling temperature of water is 98 degrees Celsius
>
> My Answer: The boiling temperature of water is NOT 98 degrees Celsius
>
> I believe I can simplify this to: The boiling temperature of water is greater than 98 degrees

Your answer is fine; your simplification is not. The negation would just say that the boiling temperature is not 98 degrees.

You could make, perhaps, an argument that if the boiling temperature of water is 98 degrees, it is also certainly any higher number (up to the conditions in which you boil water), so this in negation would translate to a lower number.

However, boiling temperature is typically defined (under fixed conditions) as a single quantity. "The boiling point is 100 degrees" means "this is boiling at any temperature of at least 100 degrees" but not "higher temperatures are boiling points."

But this is mostly semantics.

The most correct statement from the viewpoint of the mathematics is that the negation has boiling temperature not equal to 98 degrees. After all, we're simply saying we know that it's not 98, but we don't know about it being 97 or 99.

---

> 3 - Problem: 100 is a multiple of 5
>
> My Answer: 100 is NOT a multiple of 5
>
> I believe I can simplify this to: 5 does not divide 100

Your answer and "simplification" are equivalent statements, but I wouldn't say the latter is simpler, because then you have to define what you mean by "divides," which is a bit of a nontrivial thing even if it seems obvious.

---

> 4 - Problem: All students do not have 3 legs
>
> My Answer: It is not the case that all students do not have 3 legs
>
> I believe I can simplify this to: There exists at least one student with 3 legs

These are equivalent statements and equally correct. It basically amounts to whether you say "$(\forall x)(P(x))$" has negation $(\neg \forall x)(P(x))$ or $(\exists x)(\neg P(x))$. These are equivalent, but we usually default to the latter since it's easier to handle and prove. (Similar ideas mentioned in a past question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3058139/why-is-the-negation-of-the-statement-exists-x-px-given-by-forall-x-neg).)

---

> 5 - Problem: There are 13 items in a baker's dozen
>
> My Answer: There are not 13 items in a baker's dozen

Correct.

Comment: Perhaps for your response to $4$, you meant that $(\neg \forall x)(P(x))$ is equivalent to $(\exists x)(\neg P(x))$, not $(\exists x)(P(x))$.

Comment: I did, yeah; thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most of them are fine. In fact, it seems like you already have a grasp of quantifiers! The quantifier $\forall$ just means "for all" and the quantifier $\exists$ just means "there exists".

$1$, $3$ and $5$ are perfect.

For $2$, the statement "the boiling temperature of water is not $98$ degrees Celsius" is correct. The statement "the boiling temperature of water is greater than $98$ degrees Celsius" is not necessarily correct, since the boiling temperature can be less than $98$ degrees Celsius (logically).

For $4$, both of your answers are correct, but saying "it is not the case that..." just signifies that you are applying a negation. Your second statement is clearer: "there exists a student without $3$ legs".